# Changing labels with a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 10 labels. I'd like to make them visible 1 by 1 by pressing a button.

So far I've thought about this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{

}
}
```

...But I have no idea what to put in the cycle. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are the labels placed on the form or in another control e.g. a panel?

Comment: @Odrai the labels are placed on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to make one more label visible each time the user presses the button, you can use the code below. This is based on the fact that your labels are names `Label1` to `Label10`. If they are named differently, maybe replace the line `Label label =` with a `switch` statement or other way to identify the labels.

```
int visibleLabel = 1; // to define which one is to be made visible

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (visibleLabel < 10)
    {
        Label label = this.Controls.Find("Label" + visibleLabel , true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
        if (label != null) label.Visible = true;
        visibleLabel++;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain the "Label label = this.Controls.Find("Label" + visibleLabel , true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;" line? I don't understand the part where .FirstOrDefault() begins.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` returns the first item in the collection or null if the collection is empty. I'm actually expecting only one item or nothing (e.g. if the labels have different name) so it's a convenient way of doing it. You should always check if what is returned is not null though.

Answer (score 1):

Try inside this loop to do this:
if label names are Label_1, Label_2, ... etc

```
Label lbl = this.Controls.Find("Label_" + i, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
lbl.Visible = true;
```

If You need to press button 1 so label 1 would appear you can do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Label lbl = this.Controls.Find("Label_" + buttonNumber, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    lbl.Visible = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if(c is Label)
           c.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: *make them visible 1 by 1 by pressing a button.*??

Answer (score 0):

Store the index of the to-make-visible label in a variable and make them visible.

```
private int _index;
private List<Label> _listThatContainsYourLabels;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _listThatContainsYourLabels[_index++].Visible = true;
}
```